# Jquery toggle class on click, and remove class if another menu item clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".more").click(function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
        if (!$(".more").hasClass(".icon-arrow-down")) {
            // alert('Yep has class');
            $(this).toggleClass("icon-arrow-down");
            $(this).toggleClass('icon-arrow-up');
        } 
        else { 
            // alert('all ok');
        }    
    });
});
```

A little messy as i was testing some things out. Basically i have a menu, with a `.more` class added for dropdowns. People on mobile click the more, which adds a class of `.open` to the menu so people can see it. Now my problem is, this code doesn't seem to work 100% of the time.

Sometimes the classes get confused and i end up with a menu open, but a class of `icon-arrow-down` still.

And also, how would i add something in so that the `open` class gets removed if another `more` button is clicked?

Help appreciated as always.

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't you just be checking if the current element has the .icon-arrow-down class. So rather than

```
if (!$(".more").hasClass(".icon-arrow-down"))
```

this

```
if (!$(this).hasClass(".icon-arrow-down"))
```

Maybe consider using

```
$(".more").click(function(e) {

        if( $(this).hasClass("open") ) {
            $(this).removeClass("open").addClass("closed");
        } else {
            // if other menus are open remove open class and add closed
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("open").addClass("closed"); 
            $(this).removeClass("closed").addClass("open");
        }

});
```

Then use the .open and .closed class to set your arrow styles

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/AzDQm/4/).

Simple but shows you what you can do.

Comment: I get a syntax error, is it because of this line:  if( this ).hasClass("open") ) { ?

Comment: @Mat-visual Yeah, sorry. Noticed it earlier and amended code.

Answer (score 4):

In menus I always use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".more").click(function(e) {
      if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
         // if it's open then just close it
         $(this).removeClass("open");
      } else {
         // if it's closed, then close everything else and open it
         $(".more").removeClass("open");
         $(this).addClass("open");
      }
      /* TODO: now do something similar with icon-arrow */
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the class `.open` from all and then add it to the clicked one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $more = $(".more");
    $more.click(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass("open") {
            $more.removeClass("open");
        } else {
            $more.removeClass("open");
            $this.addClass("open");
        }


    });
});
```

Comment: This also throws a syntax error, think it's the var $(this) = $this; line ?

Comment: Gosh... sorry. My bad. Corrected. It should be `var $this = $(this)`